# Как правильно рассчитать силу удара?

Tags: python

Пишу симулятор боя, используя рандом (выкидывание двух кубиков). Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно написать цикл. Здоровье - это Endurance (Выносливость), сила удара считается как: Skills (Мастерство) + бросание двух кубиков. Проблема состоит в том, что условия цикла while не соблюдаются.

```
from random import choice
from time import sleep

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = choice(a) # кидание 1-го кубика
c = choice(a) # кидание 2-го кубика
Skills = int(b) + 6
Endurance = int(b) + int(c) + 12
Luck = int(c) + 6
CurrentSkills = Skills
CurrentEndurance = Endurance
CurrentLuck = Luck
EnemyEndurance = 0
EnemySkills = 0
print('Ваше мастерство =' + str(Skills))
print('Ваша выносливость =' + str(Endurance))
print('Ваша удача=' + str(Luck))
print('Первый кубик=' + str(c))
print('Второй кубик=' +str(b))
if CurrentLuck > c + b: # если ваша удача больше выкинутых двух кубиков, то бой не начинается
    print('Вы везучий')
else:
    print('Ха-ха-ха, неудачник!')
    EnemyEndurance = 8
    EnemySkills = 10
    CurrentEnemyEndurance = 0
    CurrentEnemySkills = 0
    EnemyPower = b + c + EnemySkills
    PlayerPower = b + c + CurrentSkills
    b = choice(a)
    print('Кубик  ' + str(b))
    while CurrentEndurance > 0 or EnemyEndurance > 0:
        CurrentEnemyEndurance = EnemyEndurance
        CurrentEnemySkills = EnemySkills 
        b = choice(a)
        c = choice(a)
        EnemyPower = b + c + EnemySkills
        PlayerPower = b + c + CurrentSkills
        if PlayerPower > EnemyPower:
            EnemyEndurance = EnemyEndurance - 2
            print(str(EnemyEndurance) + ')')
        else:
            CurrentEndurance = CurrentEndurance - 2
            print(str(CurrentEndurance) +'(')
```

Comment: В чём именно проблема: какой результат ожидается? Что вместо этого происходит? (Чтобы воспроизвести результат, достаточно вызвать `random.seed(123)`)

Comment: Не нужно вызывать `int()` c целыми числами на входе (можно просто убрать `int()` из кода). Можно использовать `random.randint(1, 6)` вместо `choice` в этом коде. Можно писать: `print('строка', obj)` вместо `print('строка ' + str(obj))`.

Comment: Достаточно ли заменить `or` (означает "или") на `and` (означает "и") в условии цикла?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно проблема кроется где-то в функции `choice()`, при беглом просмотре и запуске грубых ошибок не обнаружил кроме "or" в условие цикла (уходит в бесконечный цикл), дописал функцию choice и все работает.

```
def choice(list):
    return list[0]; #Для тестирования всегда беру первый элемент

    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    b = choice(a)
    c = choice(a)
    Skills = int(b) + 6
    Endurance = int(b) + int(c) + 12
    Luck = int(c) + 0 #Так же для тестирования уменьшил, чтобы быстрее попасть в условие
    CurrentSkills = Skills
    CurrentEndurance = Endurance  
    CurrentLuck = Luck
    EnemyEndurance = 0
    EnemySkills = 0
    print('Skills =' + str(Skills))
    print('Endurance =' + str(Endurance))
    print('Luck=' + str(Luck))
    print('first dice=' + str(c))
    print('second dice=' +str(b))
    if CurrentLuck > c + b:
        print('your lucky')
    else:
        print('looser!')
        EnemyEndurance = 8
        EnemySkills = 10
        CurrentEnemyEndurance = 0
        CurrentEnemySkills = 0
        EnemyPower = b + c + EnemySkills
        PlayerPower = b + c + CurrentSkills
        b = choice(a)
        print('Dice  ' + str(b))
        while CurrentEndurance > 0 and EnemyEndurance > 0: #Заменил or на and
            CurrentEnemyEndurance = EnemyEndurance
            CurrentEnemySkills = EnemySkills 
            b = choice(a)
            c = choice(a)
            EnemyPower = b + c + EnemySkills
            PlayerPower = b + c + CurrentSkills
            if PlayerPower > EnemyPower:
                EnemyEndurance = EnemyEndurance - 2
                print(str(EnemyEndurance) + ')')
            else:
                CurrentEndurance = CurrentEndurance - 2
                print(str(CurrentEndurance) +'(')
```

ВЫВОД:

```
sh-4.3$ python Newfile.py                                                                      
Skills =7                                                                                      
Endurance =14                                                                                  
Luck=1                                                                                         
first dice=1                                                                                   
second dice=1                                                                                  
looser!                                                                                        
Dice  1                                                                                        
12(                                                                                            
10(                                                                                            
8(                                                                                             
6(                                                                                             
4(                                                                                             
2(                                                                                             
0(
```

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @insolor да-да, все очень случайно)